# Best Ubuntu version for netbook

Tags: distro-recommendation

I want to update my OS to Ubuntu but I am confused about what version I should install. It has windows starter.

I have a netbook with 1.66 GHz atom N450 processor & 2GB ram

What's the best Ubuntu version to install on a such machine?

Comment: Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS I think.

Comment: I would suggest Lubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. You find the i386 iso file (32-bit) via the following link, http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/16.04.1/release/ ; scroll down to find the .1 version.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar netbook with comparable specs:

- 2G RAM
- 2x Intel Atom CPU N270 @ 1.60 GHz
- Intel 945GME x86/MMX/SSE2 graphics

I run Lubuntu 16.04 LTS on it and get reasonable performance.